# How can ViewPager's height be changed at runtime while in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE with the getRawY factor

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, touch-event, motionevent

I have a ViewPager and on touch of its tabstrip, I'm moving the whole ViewPager with the touch movement. At this point I want the ViewPager to adjust its height accordingly. I have tried:

```
vPager.setTranslationY(movableY);
vPager.getLayoutParams().height+=movableY;
vPager.requestLayout();
```

(`movableY` is the movement required in Y direction)
But results aren't satisfactory.

Comment: Can you explain what you don't find 'statisfactory' about your result? Some more info on what is happening right now that you don't like.

Comment: It's height isn't changing while inside MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.